# nginx configuration for magento 2 on domain with sub directory

Tags: nginx, magento2

I got a scenario of install different magento code on same domain, but with different subdir.

For Example:

http://foo.bar/magento1 -> magento 2.2.x -> /var/www/html/magento1

http://foo.bar/magento2 -> magento 2.3.4 -> /var/www/html/magento2

Currently nginx.magento.sample I see that only support domain w/o sub-dir.

Note: This is totally 2 different sites, not 1 site with multi domain. For Apache I can easily set that with supported .htaccess but cannot on nginx.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I think I do not understand your question? Are you asking about feasibility or do you have any issue in the process?

Comment: with magento default nginx.conf, they refer to $ROOT/pub folder but only with location / meaning domain. They are not working with domain with sub folder. I.e I want it point to $ROOT/magento1/pub folder